# Encode mp3 to playback at 1.5x speed in avconv (libav)

Tags: linux, audio, vlc-media-player, mp3, libav

I would like to take an mp3 file and re-encode it to play faster (perhaps at 1.5x speed). I primarily use avconv in debian linux, but can use any other program if recommended. I can use any operating system if linux isn't the preferred method.

I understand that VLC can play files at faster than normal speed, but I want to re-encode the files so that they can be played faster on devices that do not support VLC (such as my iphone).

Also: I am doing this for 50+ files, so an automated command-line interface would be preferable, if possible.

Any help is appreciated. And as always, thank you for your time.

Comment: Just note that this will change the pitch of the encoded file, as you are effectively discarding samples from the input data (unless you re-encode at a higher sample rate), so you may also want to apply a pitch shift to the audio signal before encoding it.

Answer (score 1):

While not a CLI method (and probably not as clean as one), this is possible in Audacity, which does support batch processing.

1. On the `File` menu, click `Edit Chains`
2. Create a new chain
3. Insert a `ChangeSpeed` command with your desired percentage
4. Insert a `ExportMp3` command
5. Close the dialog box
6. On the `File` menu, click `Apply Chains`
7. Select the chain you just created and click `Apply to files...`

Answer (score 1):

You might look at:

```
sox original.mp3 faster.mp3 tempo 1.5
```

The tempo, speed, and pitch parts of the sox man page have other options to possibly create higher quality versions or variations of speed and pitch.